# Best Utility Class Implementation

Tags: oop, class, static, utilities, utility

I have read several questions regarding when to use a utility class or any class that doesn't have a state associated with it.

My question is what is the best implementation once you have decided to use a utility class? A static class, a normal class with private constructor and only static methods (similar to java's math class), or an alternative?

I understand that this will probably depend on my specific situation but I do not have one and was looking for more general guidelines or advantages and disadvantages to each implementation method.

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you, unless you're not looking forward to `OOP`.

Answer (score 3):

**What is the best implementation once you have decided to use a utility class?**

Exactly what you proposed. Create a private constructor, make the class `final` and implement `static` utility methods. In such cases, there's no need to make things more complex.

Of course, you must be careful to not falling back into imperative/procedural programming style... just one opinion.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

For Utilty Classes for little everyday Problems like Converting Stuff etc is a static class with no constructor the best implementation. Very Handy to access:

```
Utils.ConvertDateToCake();
```

My Utility Classes which need an Constructor are implemented as Singletons. So you can access them like this:

```
DatabaseUtils.getInstance().DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Utility classes are pure evil in OOP. Check this blog post for better explanation: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

In a nutshell, utility classes bring procedural programming into OOP, making your code less testable, less maintainable/readable, and slower (!).